# "How do I view close votes and reasons?" error?

Tags: support

https://stackoverflow.com/privileges/view-close-votes says

> How do I view close votes and reasons?
>
> Click on the "close" link under any of your questions, under the
>   question text and to the left side.

Yet, I don't see that link.

[image: screenshot]

Is the advice in error, or did I miss it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your question is already closed. If it wasn't, that `reopen` link would read `close` — you can only view the vote counts during voting.

When the question is actually closed, the users who voted (and the winning close reason) are made public, anyway.

Comment: Ah, so the advice is in error. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Once the question closes, the `close` link changes to the `reopen` link.

At that point, I don't think the vote counts are available to view any longer, as the information is consolidated into the closing banner.

Answer (score 2):

The question to which the screenshot is referring is already closed; that is why you don't see the link to close it. It has been replaced from the link to reopen it.