# Where's the list of users who voted on closed question?

Tags: support, user-interface, closed-questions

["How do I view close votes and reasons?" error?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/107649/how-do-i-view-close-votes-and-reasons-error)
answer says

> When the question is actually closed, the users who voted (and the
>   winning close reason) are made public, anyway.

yet is see no list of voting users on https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7135573/how-may-one-install-visual-c-2010-express-on-windows-xp-sp2-not-sp3 .

What's up?

Comment: There is a list of one

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The list of users who voted to close that question is reported after "closed as too localized by." There is just a user who voted to close it, because that user is a moderator (diamond user), and moderator's votes are blinding, which means the vote from a moderator closes the question.

Comment: [Duplicate answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/107656/wheres-the-list-of-users-who-voted-on-closed-question/107657#107657)... :)

Answer (score 15):

It appears in the close reason.

[image: List of closers]

Because it was closed by a moderator, the list only has one node.